# Rails, Devise: Add Attributes to new created object in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This is my user_controller, which was generated by devise.

```
   def create
     super
   end
```

I want, that all new users have the role "user". I tried this:

```
   def create
     super do
       @user.roles.create(role: "user")
     end
   end
```

It doesn't work, but if I type in the same line of code in rails console, it does work.

What do I need to change in the controller, that all new users have the role "users"?

EDIT

Here is my User.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :add_user_role
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :directions
  has_many :roles, through: :directions



end

private
def add_user_role
  self.roles << Role.find_by_role("user")
end
```

After creating a new User, User has twice the role:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Role id: 21, role: "user", created_at: "2016-10-27 15:13:44", updated_at: "2016-10-27 15:13:44">, #<Role id: 21, role: "user", created_at: "2016-10-27 15:13:44", updated_at: "2016-10-27 15:13:44">]>
irb(main):002:0>
```

I have two User-Controllers, here they are:

User Controller for the admin:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :current_user_allowed?



    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end


    def update
      @user = User.find(params[:id])

      role = params[:role]
      add_user_role(@user,role)

      redirect_to root_path

    end
end

private

def current_user_allowed?
  current_user.roles.each do |role|
    if role.role == "superadmin"
      return
    end
  end
  redirect_to root_path
end

def add_user_role(user, role1)
  user.roles.create(role: role1)
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:role)
end
```

Controller from devise:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
# before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
# before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource
   #def create
    # super
   #end

  # GET /resource/edit
  # def edit
  #   super
  # end

  # PUT /resource
   #def update
    # super
   #end

  # DELETE /resource
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
  # def cancel
  #   super
  # end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_up_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_account_update_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # The path used after sign up.
  # def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts.
  # def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end


end
```

Comment: role is a column in user table? or an association?

Comment: role is an association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this logic in User model using [Active Record Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html), namely `after_create`:

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  after_create :add_user_role

private
  def add_user_role
    self.roles.create(role: "user")
  end
end
```

Comment: I can't find the User Class in ActiveRecord::Base. Can you specify, where I can find this? Or, If I have to create this file, where do I have to put it? It's called applicationrecord in my project, weird. Thanks!

Comment: The User class is the devise defined model representing the user to be managed as a login-able entity. When you run the devise set up rake task that model will be created (in terms of database). It's not a definition that lives within ActiveRecord as a child somewhere.

Comment: @jaydel The after_create is firing twice. After a new user is created, the user has the role "user" twice. Do you have any clue, why this might happen?

Comment: I don't know given the code you're showing us. For example is the after_create on the model or on the controller. I'd also like to know as it's an interesting question :)

Comment: @jaydel I added my controllers and user.rb. Do you need maybe anything else? I don't know, what else might be important for this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can have some befor create action like  [Devise wiki say](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-a-default-role-to-a-User#set-up-the-default-role-as-a-model-callback), like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
    belongs_to :user_type

    # default usert type ('Usuario')
    before_create :default_user

    ....
    def default_user
        self.user_type_id = UserType.where(name: "Usuario").first.id
    end
end
```